# jQuery scrollLeft isn't working

Tags: jquery, scroll

i've created this working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/35wkv1yj/12/

when i try to convert this into my own html file the scrollLeft function isn't working and the scrolling starts left, as always.

here is my html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

<body>
  <div class="map">map</div>
  <script>
      $("body").scrollLeft(500);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

css

```
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.map {
  width: 2000px;
  background: grey;
}
```

i've already diffrent load approaches for the script. but nothings works :/.

thanks for any help!

Comment: fiddle runs onload, your code does not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `scrollLeft` **IS** working...

But maybe you didn't notice the horizontal scroll bar not at the very left in your [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/35wkv1yj/12/)?

Here is an [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/n1575r35/) to make it more evident.
I only added 200px divs under your 2000px div...
And centered your «here is center» text.

**EDIT**

User scrolling is kept in memory by the browser.
So if the user scrolled to x=0 (complete left) or to x=780 (somewhere else), on refresh (using [F5]), the effect of `scrollLeft(500)` isn't "taken car of" by the browser and the jquery `.scrollLeft()` doesn't look to be working...

But if you hit [enter] at the end of the adress in the browser's adress bar, it ok.
`scrollLeft(500)` works.

So if you need this to work on [F5] too, the walk around I just found is to set a small 10 milliseconds delay to the scrolling...

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $("body").scrollLeft(500);
},10);
```

Comment: yes, it is working in the fiddle, but not in my sperate .html file.

in the html file it's like ther is no `scrollLeft` – the scroll bar is on the left, with no 'margin'.

Comment: Have you loaded jQuery?

Comment: Do you have a screen that is wider than 2000px?

Comment: nope. its 1440. but even when i make .map 5000px wide it doesn't work.

Comment: okay... Then can you post the entire HTML you have uncluding the `<!DOCTYPE html>` and everything to the `</html>`... Because I can't figure out your issue.

Comment: the entire HTML is in the original post.

Comment: Doh! Sorry for that.

Comment: Okay... I reproduced the issue locally here... I'm scratching my head. Hold on.

Comment: ok... I may have something here... When you "refresh" the page using [F5], the scroll do not seem to occur... But if you hit [enter] at the end of the browser's adress bar, it works. Can you tell me if it does the same on you side? I thing that on refresh, the scrolled position is kept in memory. I already noticed that without paying too much attention... It's a good feature anyway...

Comment: Found a way to make it work with [F5] too. Have a look at the edit.